# "Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext", When run sparksession on pyspark with yarn

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm a newbee to pyspark.

When I run a basic pyspark program. It tells me "Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext".

Below is my code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

CLUSTER = "topi"
QUEUE = "root.larva_growth_intelligence"

conf = SparkConf() \
        .setAppName("lihai.2") \
        .set("spark.hadoop.yarn.cluster.name", CLUSTER) \
        .set("spark.yarn.queue", QUEUE)
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .master("yarn") \
        .config(conf=conf) \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()

import time
time.sleep(10)
spark.createDataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
```

Below is exception track, It looks like the sparksession was killed:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-796ef87fdd64> in <module>
      1 import time
      2 time.sleep(10)
----> 3 spark.createDataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

......
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o115.defaultParallelism.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:

org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
......
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I wonder why it is, and want to know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you get access to the logs of your notebook? There seem to be an issue with the spark session creation.

Comment: sure, when I remove other unrelated messages. Here are some messages may be useful. It says"23/02/23 03:08:15 INFO Client: Deleted staging directory hdfs://haruna/xxxxxxxxxxx/.sparkStaging/application_1676874287999_5694360
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | No such comm target registered: jupyter.widget.control
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 570d4fba-3783-446b-9007-afac6bdf25ee"

Comment: Hi @fkjslee! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thanks for you friendly reminder, Koedlt, I barely ask questions and sorry to cause your difficulty for reading. I'll notice it next time.